# how to view submenu on click using php,html

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to view submenu after click on parent.

Classes->Primary School->(Grade1,Grade2,Grade3,Grade4,Grade5,Grade6)

Classes->Middle School->(Grade7,Grade8,Grade9)

Classes->Secondary School->(Grade10,Grade11,Grade12)

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="main-navigation">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">

                        <?php foreach ($data as $menu) { ?>
                            <?php if(!$menu->children) { ?>
                            <li><a href=""><?php echo $menu->name; ?></a></li>

                            <?php }

                               else { 

                            ?>

                            <li class="dropdown open">
                                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
                                <?php echo $menu->name; ?>
                                  <span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
                                </a>

                                <ul class="dropdown-menu open" role="menu"> 
                                <?php 
                                  foreach ($menu->children as $child) {
                                ?>
                                        <li><a href="" style="color:black;"><?php echo $child->name; ?></a></li>


                                    <?php 
                                        foreach ($child->children as $sub_child) {
                                    ?>
                                            <li class="dropdown-submenu">
                                                <a href="#" style="color:black;" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown"> <?php echo $sub_child->name; ?><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span></a>
                                                <ul class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">

                                             <?php } ?>

                                                <?php } ?>

                                </ul>
                                              </li>
                            <?php } ?>
                            <?php } ?>

                                </ul>
                            </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
```

The result:
[Problem with result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ta3E.png)

I want to view Grade 1 to Grade 6 after click on Primary school and from Grade 7 to Grade 9 after click on Middle school ...

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You have an open `<ul class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">` tag without any `<li>` or `<a>`'s being generated inside of it. Then you close two each statements before closing the `<ul>` tag.

```html
<?php foreach ($child->children as $sub_child) { ?>
<li class="dropdown-submenu">
  <a href="#" style="color:black;" class="dropdown-toggle " data-toggle="dropdown">
    <?php echo $sub_child->name; ?><span class="fa fa-angle-down"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class="dropdown-submenu" role="menu">

    <?php } ?>

    <?php } ?>

  </ul>
</li>
```

This will be causing all sorts of unintended markup output. Fix that and it should fix your problem. If not, you'll atleast be a lot closer.